# Trying to give a fade animation to my image carousel, React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to animate this image carousel in reactNative, but have no idea how to start. Read the documentation about animations but still really stuck, have no idea how to incorporate it in. I tried it this way but keep getting a big fat error. Help!

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Dimensions, Image, Animated} from 'react-native'

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

class BackgroundCarousel extends React.Component {
    scrollRef = React.createRef();
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedIndex: 0,
            opacity: new Animated.Value(0)
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        Animated.timing(this.state.opacity , {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(
                prev => ({ selectedIndex: prev.selectedIndex === 
                    this.props.images.length - 1 ? 0 : prev.selectedIndex +1 }),
            () => {
                this.scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
                    animated: true,
                    y: 0,
                    x: DEVICE_WIDTH * this.state.selectedIndex
                });
            }
            );
        }, 6000);

    };



    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.setState);
    }

    render() {
        const {images} = this.props
        const {selectedIndex} = this.state
        return (
            <Animated.Image
                onLoad={this.onLoad}
                {...this.props}
                style={[
                    {
                    opacity: this.state.opacity,
                    },
                    this.props.style,
                ]}
            />
            <View style= {{height: "100%", width: "100%"}}>
                {this.props.children}
                <ScrollView 

                horizontal 
                pagingEnabled
                scrollEnabled={false}
                ref={this.scrollRef}
                >
                    {images.map(image => (
                        <Image
                            key={image}
                            source={image}
                            style={styles.backgroundImage}
                        />
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    backgroundImage: {
        height: '100%',
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH,
    }

});
```

export default BackgroundCarousel;
Any help would be appreciated. Don't know where I'm going wrong. Basically trying to add a fade effect when my background carousel changes from image to image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed your code and removed all errors, copy-paste it in https://snack.expo.io/ and give it some time to load.

Note: I have removed this.props.images for website demo, please change in your real project.

Working fade carousal: https://snack.expo.io/@rajrohityadav/fade-carosal
But I have not implemented this using React Animation.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Dimensions, Image, Animated} from 'react-native'

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default class BackgroundCarousel extends React.Component {
    scrollRef = React.createRef();
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedIndex: 0,
            opacity: new Animated.Value(0)
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        Animated.timing(this.state.opacity , {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(
                prev => ({ selectedIndex: prev.selectedIndex === 
                    3 - 1 ? 0 : prev.selectedIndex +1 }),
            () => {
                this.scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
                    animated: true,
                    y: 0,
                    x: DEVICE_WIDTH * this.state.selectedIndex
                });
            }
            );
        }, 6000);

    };



    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.setState);
    }

    render() {
        const images =[
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/dragon-scream-vector-illustration-tshirt-260nw-1410107855.jpg','https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/dragon-head-vector-illustration-mascot-600w-1201914655.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/b7/1a/bb/b71abb6dd7678bbd14a1f56be5291747--dragon-illustration-samurai-tattoo.jpg']//this.props
        const {selectedIndex} = this.state
        return (
          <>
            <Animated.Image
                onLoad={this.onLoad}
                {...this.props}
                style={[
                    {
                    opacity: this.state.opacity,
                    },
                    this.props.style,
                ]}
            />
            <View style= {{height: "100%", width: "100%"}}>
                {this.props.children}
                <ScrollView 

                horizontal 
                pagingEnabled
                scrollEnabled={false}
                ref={this.scrollRef}
                >
                    {images.map(image => (
                        <Image
                            key={image}
                            source={image}
                            style={styles.backgroundImage}
                        />
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
            </>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    backgroundImage: {
        height: '100%',
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH,
    }

});
```

Comment: It was a big help, just one thing. My background carousel is working, but I wanted to add the fading animation to it. Like it fades from one picture to the next instead of sliding from one image to the next. How does one achieve this? Thanks in advance Raj.

Comment: Also tried using your code, says the <Image> tag can not contain children as an error.

Comment: <Image> tag can not contain children, indicates you are trying <image></image>.
But the image tag only supports <image/>.

Working slides
https://snack.expo.io/@rajrohityadav/image-carosal

Comment: For fading, you want to fade-in or fade-out or both?

Also, if you are fading both ways, then why do you need to slide? Images will be hidden at load, the user can't see slide animation then.

Please explain more or share a working example, gif, video or something.

Comment: I have a working fade carousal snack here, https://snack.expo.io/@rajrohityadav/fade-carosal

This is not using animation.

Comment: I do NOT want slide, just fade in and out :) Is that code is a perfect example. There seems to be a small lag time in the transition between two slides?

Comment: No, that code is not a perfect example. 
You can edit lag by changing setTimeout time, feel free to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple & optimized library [react-native-fadecarousel](https://github.com/aliunco/react-native-fadecarousel) and use it like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import FadeCarousel from 'react-native-fadecarousel';

const FadeCarouselScreen = () => {

    const images = [
        'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/dragon-scream-vector-illustration-tshirt-260nw-1410107855.jpg',
        'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/dragon-head-vector-illustration-mascot-600w-1201914655.jpg',
        'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/b7/1a/bb/b71abb6dd7678bbd14a1f56be5291747--dragon-illustration-samurai-tattoo.jpg'
    ];

    return <FadeCarousel
                loop 
                fadeAnimationDuration={1000} 
                autoPlay={{enable: true , delay: 1000 }}>
        { 
            images.map((image, index) => {
                return <View key={`slide ${index}`} style={styles.slideItem}>
                    <Image style={styles.image} resizeMethod="resize" resizeMode="cover" source={{ uri: image }}/>
                </View>
            })
        }
    </FadeCarousel>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 300
    },
    slideItem: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 300,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignContent: "center"
    }
})

export default FadeCarouselScreen
```